# Rendering without lighting

Tags: rendering

It's really urging for me to know what's going on. I'm trying to render my kitchen in Blender as shown in the picture but when I render, there is no lighting whatsoever. I am using [PyClone](https://creativedesigner3d.com/pyclone/) addon if that matters.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Since you are posting the first time and you didn't gave us any useful information pls provide blend file. thx.

Comment: Well, maybe you could give us at least a little more information on your scene. As far as I understand, PyClone lets you add the interior objects of the kitchen... but do you have any lights in your scene? Do you have lights inside the kitchen?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have any lights, or you have some wrong rendering setting. Please provide more details, screenshots and if needed, the blender file itself. It'll help us to know what the problem is exactly and provide you a proper solution.

Comment: First time I tried to add lights was by clicking on Wall Prompts. However, Wall Prompts is not showing! I tried to use lighting addons but all in vain.

Comment: Is there a way I can share the blender file to you guys so you can check it?